# How to refer GetOptions of special character?

Tags: perl, special-characters, getopt

I'm using `GetOptions` to act as a switch in my Perl code. I have an array that needs to be separated by a special character.  Currently, I can write this following code.

```
&GetOptions('sep:i');
if ($opt_sep) {
    $sep = "\.";
} else {
    $sep = "\/";
}
```

When I try `-sep 1`, my output will be `Flower.Red.Small`.  Without this statement or `-sep 0` , my output will be `Flower/Red/Small`. Any idea how to exactly refer to any special character which user defined to separate my output statement? The separator may be any character of:

`# @ ^ * & % ; -`

Comment: Unrelated to your main question, but supplying an option with a default is better done via: `my %opts=(sep=>"\/"); &GetOptions (\%opt, 'sep:i');` and then simply use `$opt{sep}` in the rest of the code.

Comment: And just a suggestion: You don't need to use & at the beginning of the subroutine call. You can just write GetOptions(...)

Comment: @DVK , i is refer to integer right? Special character is invalid if i assign `sep:i`?

Comment: @annel - of course. "Copy/paste considered harmful". Good catch. `sep:s`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the following?

```
my @fields = split /\Q$opt_sep/, $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s` (string) instead of `i` (integer).  Refer to [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my %opt = (sep => '/');
GetOptions(\%opt, 'sep=s');

my @stuff = qw(Flower Red Small);
print join($opt{sep}, @stuff), "\n";

__END__

script.pl -sep /
Flower/Red/Small

script.pl -sep .
Flower.Red.Small

script.pl -sep @
Flower@Red@Small
```

Comment: Somehow i get unknown option of sep.